# How to adjust the viewing window of .mhd file to get a better look at medical images?

Tags: python-3.x, dicom, medical, pydicom, simpleitk

I load some .mdh and .raw files for medical images, but one thing bothers me. I understand that in .dicom file, you can convert pixel intensity to HU by using rescale.slope and rescale.intercept, which .mhd file fail to include. Therefore, I am wondering how I can get a better view of my image data from .mdh and  .raw file.This is the [image](https://github.com/yujuezhao/hello-world/blob/master/lung.png) that I generate, this is the kind of [image](https://github.com/yujuezhao/hello-world/blob/master/lung%202.png) that I want to accomplish.
Here I load a slice from the data, and plot the [histogram](https://github.com/yujuezhao/hello-world/blob/master/hist.png) of the values of each 'pixel' (no sure whether to call them pixel or voxel).
Though I do get an idea to simply reset the pixel with the smallest value, I really want to hear from the experienced peers if there is any more sophisticated way to achieve this.

```
itk_img = SimpleITK.ReadImage(mhd_file) 
img_array = SimpleITK.GetArrayFromImage(itk_img)
plt.imshow(img_array[80], cmap=plt.cm.gray) # show a slice from a 3D data
plt.show()

plt.hist(img_array[80].flatten(), bins=80, color='c')
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```

I have uploaded all my pictures to github since I am yet allowed to upload images, so please feel free to click in.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values stored in an .mhd/.mha file are already the HU values. What you are thinking of is the [Window and Level](http://what-when-how.com/embedded-image-processing-on-the-tms320c6000-dsp/windowlevel-image-processing-part-1/) of an image viewer, which remaps HU values to pixel values that can be displayed on a monitor.

I don't recommend rescaling the values in the files themselves, as that will result in a loss of information. Rather, I suggest downloading a program capable of displaying the images, such as [ITK-Snap](http://www.itksnap.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php) and/or [MeVisLab](https://www.mevislab.de/), which allows you to adjust your window and level

Comment: Thanks for your advise. Btw, can I understand ' a loss of information'  in this way. That is, rescaling the values directly in the files could probably undermine the performance of my neural network when I use these files as training dataset.

Comment: Most likely, yes. As [HU values closely correlate with the tissue types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hounsfield_scale#Value_in_parts_of_the_body), changing the values can result in misidentification.

Answer (score 2):

The previous answer does a good job of explaining why windowing is what you want, not a rescaling of the intensity values. However, the proposed solution by @Czorio involves you visualizing the image in 3rd party software (ITK-Snap or MeVisLab).

While I would also recommend using these apps, it looks like in your post, you are trying to visualize the image in Python using Matplotlib. If you want to change the windowing in Python, I would suggest modifying the `clim` parameter in `plt.imshow`. For instance:

```
import numpy as np

itk_img = SimpleITK.ReadImage(mhd_file) 
img_array = SimpleITK.GetArrayFromImage(itk_img)
plt.imshow(img_array[80], cmap=plt.cm.gray, clim=np.percentile(img_array, (1,99)))
plt.show()

plt.hist(img_array[80].flatten(), bins=80, color='c')
plt.xlabel("Value")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```

In the modified code above, I am simply rescaling the colormap `plt.cm.gray` to the 1st to 99th percentiles of the values in your image. You will need to play around with these percentiles until you get an image that you like (this will depend on factors such as the anatomy you are visualizing). You can use the histogram as well to aid your decision.

You can modify the `cmap` and `clim` even further to achieve non-linear colormapping, which you might want depending once again on the anatomy you are trying to visualize.

Answer (score 1):

I'd just echo what's been said as well.  I do a lot of work with dicom/diagnostic images as well, with analysis and ML.

A key point to spell out specifically (I'm assuming you know this, and the other replies make that knowledge implicitly) is that these images (you're using CT, but same applies for MR and other modalities) is that the **image data itself is 16 bit**.  (ie value ranges over a 65,536 set of values, not 256 like 8 bit data).

There are two important points about that:

- For *any* machine learning/analysis y**ou must use the 16 bit data**, not any 8 bit representation of it.  I say 'must' because *a) if you don't you're loosing most of the information in the data b) the specific values (for CT) have clinical significance and c) you're not going to have a hope in hell of any clinical regulatory approval/use/testing/validation if you're not using the 16 bit data*
- When you want to **visualize the data**, you need to convert it into a (usually) 8-bit downsampled version - ie somehow represent it as 256 discrete values instead of 65k.

What you're doing above is trying to visualize the entire 16-bit dataset (which means somehow downsampling to 256 grey values).

By default, matplotlib imshow - for 16bit data - will set the greyscale limits as the min and max of the data.  This almost certainly (see below) will not get you an image like the ones you want, or is useful for anyone.

To get the images view you want, you need to pass vmin/vmax to imshow() to tell matplotlib what the min and max greyscale values (ie what value is black and what is white):

```
vmin = -100
vmax = 200
plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

# or if you're using window/level:
window = 300
level = 100
vmin = level - window/2
vmax = level + window/2
plt.imshow(img_array, cmap='gray', vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)
```

*I say almost certainly, because in CT images the min value for most scanners in an image is -3000 (or some equivalent very low value).  This is because while air has a HU value of -1000, the scanners have a circular field of view they get image data over.  Outside that FOV, they set the data to this "low" value to indicate it's not actual real scanned data.  You can see this in your image [here](https://github.com/yujuezhao/hello-world/blob/master/lung.png), where there is the body, the air outside the body (the mid-grey values - around -1000 HU), then the black values outside of that circular region (which are probably around -3000 HU).*